# Node MS SQL max pool size

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am using https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql for Database queries,
I have initialized connection as follows:

```
var config = {
        user: settings[dbName].userName,
        password: settings[dbName].password,
        server: settings[dbName].host,
        database: settings[dbName].database,
        port: settings[dbName].port,
        options: {
            tdsVersion: '7_1',
            instance: settings[dbName].instance
        }
    };
```

Here i am not giving any pool size, and by default pool size is 10, is there anyway i can set infinite pool size as i have set infinite connection pool in MS SQL.

Comment: What would be the point of an infinite connection *pool*? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have created a Web API that will have 10000+ calls to database, and its giving me error when i do load testing. Error is Database connection timeout.

Comment: I want to set connection pool size to infinite (i.e. what ever pool size database support)

Comment: Have the same issue while I am trying to parse an xml file line by line and insert a column to a Sql Table.